# Problems when using tf.data.Dataset.batch

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I want to make clear how tf.data.Dataset.batch work with my dataset. The dataset is as follows:

```
dataset = tf.convert_to_tensor([[5.1, 3.3, 1.7, 0.5, ],
[5.9, 3.0, 4.2, 1.5],
[6.9, 3.1, 5.4, 2.1],
[2.3, 1.3, 6.4, 9.3]])
```

Then I use batch method:

```
dataset = dataset.batch(2)
```

and iterate the dataset once.

```
x = tfe.Iterator(dataset).next()
```

As I suppose, the result should be a 2*4 array, but it returns the whole 4*4 dataset.

Could anyone give me some details about how to apply the `batch` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your `dataset` `Tensor` into a `TensorSliceDataset`, i.e. telling Tensorflow to slice the tensor and make a dataset of it.

```python
import tensorflow as tf

data = tf.convert_to_tensor([[5.1, 3.3, 1.7, 0.5],
                             [5.9, 3.0, 4.2, 1.5],
                             [6.9, 3.1, 5.4, 2.1],
                             [2.3, 1.3, 6.4, 9.3]])

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data).batch(2)
batch_iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
batch = sess.run(batch_iterator)
print(batch)
# [[ 5.1   3.3  1.7  0.5  ]
#  [ 5.9   3.   4.2  1.5  ]]
```